# jBehave write common step

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

Can I have the following step method using jBehave;

```
@When("I select action <actionText> on <panelTitle>")
@Alias("I select action $actionText on $panelTitle")
public void myMethod(@Named("actionText") String actionText, @Named("panelTitle") String panelTitle) {
    // My code
}
```

So as you can see, the step text is the same. Only thing is in one case, the value is through 
parameter injection and in other it is through parameterised scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar implementation in link: 
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html

So, you can use this method.